# Hibernate search index location issue

Tags: hibernate, search, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate search with Spring Boot. I am specifying the index location using the following properties in application.properties file.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider: filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase: /opt/indexes/lucene/
```

My POM file has the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Optional: to use JPA 2.1 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also have an ApplicationListener that builds the index when the context is reloaded.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Component
public class BuildSearchIndex implements ApplicationListener {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(BuildSearchIndex.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            try {
                FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =        Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error("InterruptedException while trying to index entities for search", e);
        }
    }
    return;
}
}
```

The issue I am running into is that when the application starts up, the index is created in the specified location, but then the load fails with the stack trace below:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.ab.irh.model.Publication
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:265)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:528)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:495)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:104)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:363)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:219)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:143)
at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:74)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:588)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
... 41 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to initialize directory provider: com.ab.irh.model.Publication
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:91)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:212)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:99)
at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:261)
... 57 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Cannot write into index directory: /. for index com.ab.irh.model.Publication
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:274)
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:237)
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:66)
at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:88)
... 60 more
```

I can't figure out why the application is trying to access the /. directory. Has anyone else run into similar issues?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is happening on Amazon EC2. The index location and search functionality work fine on localhost.

Comment: For the record: I have a similar problem running on wildly 9.0.2, on Ubuntu 16.04. When starting wildfly with init.d-scripts or standalone.sh the indexBase that is configured in persistence.xml is used, while starting using systemd it is ignored and lucene tries to use /.